# Trying to add a scrollbar to a JPanel with GridLayout, but the JCheckBoxes just get made smaller instead

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane

So I'm trying to set up a Gui in Java which holds a list of checkboxes. What determines the length of the list is the highlighted checkboxes. However, when I add more things to the list the checkboxes just get smaller to fit the panel. I've added a vertical scrollbar, but this just doesn't do anything. Is there something I have to do to stop the GridLayout from resizing what it holds or is it the wrong layout?

```
   package darrt;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TestForScrollBat {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TestForScrollBat();
    }
    public TestForScrollBat(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        scrollPane.setBounds(50, 30, 300, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("           Soc Categories");

        JCheckBox soc1 = new JCheckBox("Blood and Lymphatic System Disorder");
        JCheckBox soc2 = new JCheckBox("Cardiac Disorders");
        JCheckBox soc3 = new JCheckBox("Congenital, familial and Genetic Disorders");
        JButton jbtn = new JButton("Go!");
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(soc1);
        panel.add(soc2);
        panel.add(soc3);
        panel.add(jbtn);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();


      frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I had it before so that it would add a scroll to this panel, but now it doesn't even do that.. It just creates a new JPanel on the JFrame

Comment: Your code has errors and does not compile because it does not find the variables like: `Lists` and `testmain`. Would you please provide a minimal, runnable code which shows your problem?

Comment: This answer may help you. [A similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962496/swing-gridbaglayout-with-screen-resizing)

Comment: @STaefi Okay I have redone this now :)

Comment: Your minimal code is good now! Minimal good codes will get minimal good answers ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is about the following lines in your code:

```
scrollPane.setBounds(50, 30, 300, 50);
```

You should **not** set static sizes and locations when using layouts. You are telling a specific size and location to the `scrollPane` while you had add it to the `center` of the `contentPane` before. These two are in conflict.

And next problem is about this line:

```
frame.add(panel);
```

This line will detach the `panel` from you `JScrollPane` and add it directly to the `contentPane` of the `JFrame`.

By deleting/commenting these lines, your problem will be solved.